# Convert Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> to Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, lambda, html-helper

I have a custom HtmlHelper extension, which renders controls based on teh helper input parameters.

I am in a situation, where, I am able to render any control, except a CheckBox. As the CheckBoxFor helper accepts, `Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>`

I need a way to convert the return-type of the Func to bool, as mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could translate the lambda:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyHelper<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex
    )
    {
        if (typeof(TProperty) != typeof(bool))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can only generate checkboxes with boolean properties on your view model");
        }

        var boolExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(ex.Body, ex.Parameters);

        return html.CheckBoxFor(boolExpression);
    }
}
```

Now you could use the helper on boolean properties on your model:

```
@Html.MyHelper(x => x.SomeBooleanProperty)
```

Comment: When I have a nested property like `Foo.Bar[0].Stick[0].Checked`, then the generated html, name attribute must be like name=`Foo.Bar[0].Stick[0].Checked` as the built-in CheckBoxFor does. Your solution, generates the name attribute as name=`Checked`. :-(

Comment: Ah, my bad, I used `Foo.Bar.First().Stick.First().Checked`, instead of `Foo.Bar[0].Stick[0].Checked`. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I wish I could have given you 10 upvotes at least, considering the amount of time I've been searching for the right answer to this problem. Thank you!